# Evaluation of the integral of $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ over a disk

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, polar-coordinates

> Show that
>   $$\renewcommand{\intd}{\,\mathrm{d}}
>     \iint_{D(R)} e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \intd x \intd y = \pi \left(1 - e^{-R^2}\right)$$
>   where $D(R)$ is the disc of radius $R$ with center $(0,0).$

I have never been asked to calculate a double integral without a defined region, so I don't even know where to start. I don't know the boundaries.

This is my guess:

$$0 < r < R\\
0 < \theta < 2\pi $$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is one of the most famous integrals in calculus, in particular when $R\to\infty$. It's really good for you to understand what's happening here.

Comment: Now you should be able to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$. "A mathematics is one to whom that is as obvious as that twice two makes four is to you." - Lord Kelvin

Comment: Hahaha that's the next question in my exercise book.

Comment: i remember there's even a paper for such trick, analyzing if it's special or can be generalized...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using polar coordinates the boundaries are:
$$0 \leq r \leq R \\
  0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$$

Since $D(R)$ is the disk of radius $R$ with center at $(0,0)$:
$D(R)=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \leq R^2\}$

So we have the following:

$$x = r\cos \theta, y = r \sin\theta \\
  \renewcommand{\intd}{\,\mathrm{d}}
  \intd x \intd y = r \intd r \intd \theta$$
$$
\begin{align}
  \iint_{D(R)} e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \intd x \intd y
  &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^R e^{-r^2} r \intd r \intd \theta \\
  &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^R \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\intd r} \left( -\frac{1}{2} e^{-r^2} \right) \intd r \intd \theta \\
  &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \left( -\frac{1}{2} e^{-r^2} \right )_0^R \intd \theta \\
  &= \int_0^{2 \pi} -\frac{1}{2} \left( e^{-R^2} - 1 \right) \intd \theta \\
  &= -\frac{1}{2} \left( e^{-R^2} - 1 \right) 2 \pi \\
  &= -\pi \left( e^{-R^2} - 1 \right) \\
  &= \pi \left( 1 - e^{-R^2} \right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Good job ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{} $

Comment: There is a little mistake in this answer: The $R$ on the right side of the definition of D(R) should be $R^{2}$.

Comment: Yes,you're right..I will edit my answer..

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$, then
$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^R r e^{-r^2} \,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

You have a defined region to integrate about, which is $D(R)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}| x^{2}+y^{2} \leq R^{2}\}$ as the disc with radius $R$.

At first, you should choose an adequate parametrization for making the problem easier. Here you might use the transformation $(r, \theta) \mapsto (x, y)=(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ with $r \in [0, R]$, $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.